# Numerical solution of the hyperbolic equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve the following hyperbolic equation with given boundary conditions:

[image: two muppets]

I choose as initial condition $u=1$, and evolve the above hyperbolic equation until reaching a stationary state with some predetermined tolerance.

Spatial derivatives are approximated by taking standard centered differences everywhere.

The *Mathematica* input is:

```
φ[z] = q*(1/z + (-1*q)/(-1*z));
η[z] := k* (1/z + (-1*q)/(-1*z)); 
r[ρ, z] := sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2];

NDSolve[ {Derivative[u[t, ρ, z], {t, 2}] == 
   Derivative[u[t, ρ, z], {ρ, 2}] + (1/ρ)*
     Derivative[u[t, ρ, z], {ρ, 1}] +  
    Derivative[
     u[t, ρ, z], {z, 2}] - ((φ[z]^4)/4)* ( 
      Derivative[(η[z] + u[t, ρ, z]  - 1)/φ[
           z], {ρ, 
          1}] Derivative[(η[z] + u[t, ρ, z]  + 
            1)/φ[z], {ρ, 1}] + 
       Derivative[(η[z] + u[t, ρ, z]  - 1)/φ[
           z], {z, 
          1}] Derivative[(η[z] + u[t, ρ, z]  + 
            1)/φ[z], {z, 1}]) *((η[z] + 
          u[t, ρ, 
           z])*((η[z] + u[t, ρ, z])^2 - (φ[z]^2)/
           2) )^(-1), u[0, ρ, z] = 0, u[t, 6, z] = 1, 
  u[t, ρ, -6] = u[t, ρ, 6]}, 
 u[t, ρ, z], {t, 0, 10}, {ρ, 0, 6}, {z, -6, 6}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]
```

which gives errors.

I would like to ask if you could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Irina, could you please retype Mathematica's input in a form one could copy to notebook?

Comment: Gregory Rut, I'm new at this website, and couldn't find a way to appropriate form. I'll be glad if you make changes for any convenience.

Comment: @Irina, copy the code directly from the notebook and paste it into the edit window.  Then select the code and press the code button, which looks like two braces, {}, above the edit window.

Comment: And don't TeX $ on the code.

Comment: @Michael E2, thanks for the tip. Now, please, can someone help me to handle this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you want `=` and not `==` in the initial conditions?

Comment: Also `Derivative[f,{t,2}]` isn't correct syntax

Comment: are you sure you did not made a mistake with the second parametric equation? It seams that you might wanted Eta in terms of rho and not z

Answer (score 3):

Comment: I think you want [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/D.html) instead of [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Derivative.html).  Also `==` instead of `=`.  And you probably want the functions defined with patterns `z_` etc.  But there are errors that you'll have to address.  (Or perhaps someone else.)

```
ClearAll[φ, η, r, u];
φ[z_] = q*(1/z + (-1*q)/(-1*z));
η[z_] := k*(1/z + (-1*q)/(-1*z));
r[ρ_, z_] := Sqrt[ρ^2 + z^2];

pde = D[u[t, ρ, z], {t, 2}] == 
   D[u[t, ρ, z], {ρ, 2}] + (1/ρ)*D[u[t, ρ, z], {ρ, 1}] + 
    D[u[t, ρ, z], {z, 2}] - ((φ[z]^4)/4)*
      (D[(η[z] + u[t, ρ, z] - 1)/φ[z], {ρ, 1}] D[(η[z] + u[t, ρ, z] + 1)/φ[z], {ρ, 1}] + 
       D[(η[z] + u[t, ρ, z] - 1)/φ[z], {z, 1}] D[(η[z] + u[t, ρ, z] + 1)/φ[z], {z, 1}])*
         ((η[z] + u[t, ρ, z])*((η[z] + u[t, ρ, z])^2 - (φ[z]^2)/2))^(-1);
bc = {u[0, ρ, z] == 0,
   u[t, 0, z] == 1,
   u[t, ρ, -6] == u[t, ρ, 6]};

NDSolve[{pde, bc}, 
 u[t, ρ, z], {t, 0, 10}, {ρ, 0, 6}, {z, -6, 6}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]
```

> NDSolve::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable. >>

I'll leave this up for a while, but I'll probably delete it since it is not an answer. :( Unless I forget.  Maybe someone else can use it.

**Update**

`q` and `k` have to be given numeric values for `NDSolve` to work.  In `NDSolve`, `ρ` starts at `0` and there's a `1/ρ` in the PDE, which will give you a `1/0` error (when the `NDSolve` finally works).  There may be other such singularities to deal with, but this one was obvious.

Here `NDSolve` goes to work but gives the `1/0` error.  The trick to get it to work is to give a complete IVP for `t`.  The highest order derivative is two, so initial values for `u` and its `t` derivative have to be given.  (I *do not know* if this is how you should fix your problem.)

```
q = 2; k = 1/10; (* random values)
bc = {u[0, ρ, z] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, ρ, z] == 1,
   u[t, 0, z] == 1,
   u[t, ρ, -6] == u[t, ρ, 6]};
NDSolve[{pde, bc},
 u[t, ρ, z],
 {t, 0, 10}, {ρ, 0, 6}, {z, -6, 6}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]
```

At this point, I believe I am stuck.  The problem, I believe, is now a mathematical/scientific one of what the appropriate boundary and initial conditions are.  It is also possible that there is an error (typo) in the PDE.

If you need to vary `q` and `k` as parameters, consider using [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html).  But the basic `NDSolve` problem should be fixed first.

Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Maybe someone more familiar with the solver for PDEs can. In any case I think the way to go with these things is to start small and build up, not write a big piece of code and then start trying to weed out various syntax errors, only to encounter algorithmic errors.

Comment: @Michael E2, thanks. I got the same error message and have no idea how to correct.

Comment: @Irina `Sqrt` instead of `sqrt`